# Finding second smallest eigenvector of symmetric matrix in java

Tags: image, matrix, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am writing some code for a clustering algorithm in Java.

I am required to work out the second smallest eigenvector of some fairly large symmetric (sparse) matrices, and currently I use a library to work out ALL eigenvalues.

Does anyone have any hints/advice as to how we can calculate/estimate only the smallest eigenvector? I am hoping this will be more efficient :)

It is obviously extremely slow to calculate them all.

Comment: can you show your code you have tried already?

Comment: Usually people use the [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) or Lanczos iteration to calculate a few of the biggest or smallest eigenvalues, e.g., in Matlab's [`eigs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) documentation shows what it can do. Matlab and [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) and [Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.4.7/stdlib/linalg/?highlight=eigs#Base.eigs) wrap a Fortran library called ARPACK but for JVM, you may have to implement it yourself, or find an ARPACK wrapper.

Comment: (N.B. Julia >=0.7 has `eigs` in [Arpack.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/Arpack.jl) package, not in base.)